error on trying to verify solidity contract with Hardhat for Etherscan
I am trying to verify and submit my contract source code to etherscan using hardhat but I am running into the following error and I do not understand how to resolve the error. I've read through the code and I cannot spot what I am doing incorrectly. Please can someone advise?
my verify code
async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
  console.log("Verifying Contract...")
  try {
    await run("verify : verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      constructorArguments: args,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already Verified!")
    } else {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}

here's what I'm trying to run
yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia

here's the error
error = new Error(message);
                    ^
Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "retrieve", "signature": "retrieve()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.12.0)
    at makeError (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:694:21)
    at assert (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:715:25)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/interface.ts:916:15)
    at staticCallResult (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:346:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at staticCall (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:303:24)
    at Proxy.retrieve (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:351:41)
    at main (/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/scripts/deploy.js:16:24)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

